# Is it possible to open a popup based on php condition

Tags: php, javascript

I have got a situation where I need to fire an affiliate pixel based on a RESTful webservice request and a condition. These conditions are present in a method of class.

Initially I tried firing the pixel through curl by downloading the link in the pixel. That did not work and my affiliate said the pixel should be fired only through browser.

What came to my mind was open a pop up based on those conditions and load this pixel in that popup and close the popup again after 10 seconds. Opening a popup is possible through Javascript event. But I don't know if we can open the popup based on my requirements.

Any suggestions might help. Thanks.

**Update:**

```
<?php
apiClass{
    method()
    {
        if(condition1)
        {
            echo "<open popup1 through js>"//Or any other solution
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<open popup2 through js>"//Or any other solution
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Definitely possible. What are the conditions?

Comment: Dynamically tell javascript to or to not make a pop-up based on some PHP calculation perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var popup = null; //this is js
<?php
if(condition1) ?>
  popup = <?= echo something ?>
<?php else ?>
  popup = <?= echo something ?>

  switch(popup){
  case "xxx":
    //open here 
  break;
  case "yyy":
    //open here
  break;
  }
```

you can initialize variables in js using php and then when ur page is ready u can check the variable and open popup accordingly.